# Symfony2 swiftmailer no errors, message not received

Tags: php, email, symfony, gmail, swiftmailer

I'm struggling with Symfony2 sending e-mails via SwiftMailer (working on localhost). I searched through documentation and different posts on stackoverflow for configurations and I managed to apply the configuration that won't make any errors but the messages are not coming to the inbox. Please take a quick look, maybe something small is missing:

parameters.yml

```
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_host:      ~
    mailer_user:      mark.twain3445@gmail.com
    mailer_password:  Testing1
```

config_dev.yml

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    username:  mark.twain3445@gmail.com
    password:  Testing1
```

in controller:

```
    public function sendMail(Request $request)
        {   
            $defaultData = array('name' => '', 'email' => '', 'subject' => '', 'message' => '');
            $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('email', 'email')
            ->add('subject', 'text')
            ->add('message', 'textarea')
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Send'))
            ->getForm();

            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $name = $form['name']->getData();
                $email = $form['email']->getData();
                $subject = $form['subject']->getData();
                $message_mail = $form['message']->getData();
                var_dump($name);


            $mailer = $this->get('mailer');
            $message = $mailer->createMessage()
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setFrom($email)
            ->setTo('mark.twain3445@gmail.com')
            ->setBody($message_mail);
            $mailer->send($message);

            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look in your gmail account, you can find a mail saying that there is some suspicious activity caused by your remote server, change the security settings and it should work.

To change this setting go to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and turn on Access for less secure apps

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Actually, something like this appeared and I said to google that the activity was mine. Is it not enough?

Comment: I have Access for less secure apps turned off and still nothing

Comment: I think that something else was necessary, I will look at my account

Comment: You have to activate the access for less secure apps, it looks like reverse logic at https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

You should go on your gmail account activate remote access.

Also please verify that you dont have this in your configuration :

disable_delivery:  true

During your dev phase, you can add this in your configuration :

swiftmailer:
    delivery_address:  dev@example.com

so all the mails will be sent to dev@exemple.com whatever you set as TO.